# How to assign the root DNS as a folder

Tags: dns

I am wanting to change the root address of my domain to `31.xx.xxx.xx/folder/`. How can I go about doing this?

I know that within the "zone file" I can edit the "A(host)" to the ip `31.xx.xxx.xx` and that will work but I can not assign it as a folder!

Comment: This question doesn't make sense - DNS has (essentially) one job, converting names to numbers. Beyond that it's all down to what's listening. I.e., your web server etc

Comment: How can I do it with my webserver?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I wish I could post a link...  but I suggest you read Chapters 1-5 of the book `DNS and BIND`, then reformulate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is impossible. DNS only maps domain names to IP addresses, like to allow a browser to find the web server (or to allow email software to find the target SMTP server, and so on). Next, the browser will tell the server for which domain it wants the web site; see [What exactly happens when you browse a website in your browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/31468/what-exactly-happens-when-you-browse-a-website-in-your-browser)

Likewise, you cannot map some specific URL to another server, or map a domain to a specific port.

If your web server needs to handle requests for multiple domains, you need something called "virtual hosting", to map domains to folders. If you only have one domain, you somehow need to tell your web server to set the root of the website to the specific folder.

Comment: Although I agree with you, this is technically (and stricto sensu) not entirely true. You can perform a pseudo mapping to ports using an SRV record (if the application layer of a client supports SRV records of course); likewise, DNS servers are not only used to map domain names to IP addresses (MX records are one example).

Comment: The only application that widely uses SRV records is Microsoft Active Directory.  Not much else uses them though -- e.g., some SIP phones -- despite their universal design for better load balancing & redirection.  So they could be used for web services, but no browsers implement SRV lookups for HTTP services or other services.

Comment: Thank you for telling me to look into virtual hosting! I have since found this tutorial, which worked perfectly! https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts